# Can I always use "'d" as contraction of "did"?

Tags: word-usage, contractions

Two [different](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/8061/95) [answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/8062/95) for a question say that *'d* in "How'd you know?" is a contraction of *did*.
Can I always use *'d* as contraction of *did*, or should I use it only when *'d* follows a word that is part of a set of words?

For example, could I write "I'd know it." or should I write only *why'd*, *who'd*, *where'd*, *when'd*, and *how'd*?

I checked the NOAD, but it says that *'d* is a contraction for *had* and *would*; the same is said from the OALD, which says that *he'd* is a short form for *he had* or *he would*. Both the dictionaries didn't help to understand when I could use *'d* instead of *did*.

Comment: Note that you *can* say "I'd know it"... but only if you mean "I would know it". :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only contract *did* (or any other word, for that matter) when it is **unstressed**.

You cannot, for instance, contract "I did know it", because *did* is only used there to give emphasis to your assertion that you knew it: "I **did** know it".

And you can't contract *did* when it is the main verb of an indicative sentence, or (as David Schwartz points out) the 'stranded' tensed verb of a clause:

> <sup>✲</sup>I'd it. *for* I did it.
>   <sup>✲</sup>He didn't know it, but I'd. *for* He didn't know it, but I did.

But in questions headed by an interrogative, when *did* is only there for *DO-support*, the interrogative takes the emphasis, and *did* can be contracted.

- How'd you do it?  ... Note that in speech the *'d you* will ordinarily be elided to /dʒə/, "Howdja do it?"
- Why'd he do it?
- When'd they do it?

---

<sup>✲</sup> *marks a usage as unacceptable*

Comment: So around Christmas time is it correct to say what'd you get? For what did you get? Or is that grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @jessica - "What'd you get?" is how "What did you get?" is informally pronounced (in American English), but it is almost always transcribed as "What did you get?".